# How to make a 3d effect on bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

I have a very simple basic bar's graphic like this one
[image]

but i want to display the bars with some 3d effect, like this 
[image]

I just want the bars to have that 3d effect...my code is:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(4.6,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,ylabel="Valeur",xlabel="Code",autoscale_on=True)

width = 0.35
ind = np.arange(len(values))
rects = ax1.bar(ind, values, width, color='#A1B214')
ax1.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax1.set_xticklabels( codes )
ax1.set_ybound(-1,values[0] * 1.1)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
```

i've been looking in the gallery of matplotlib,tried a few things but i wasn't lucky, Any ideas? Thxs

Comment: You might be able to work something out with [`mplot3d`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html#mplot3d-example-code-bars3d-demo-py).

Comment: u_U i'm beeing forced by the one that signs my check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Matplotlib doesn't **by design** support features like the "3D" effect you just mentioned. I remember reading about this some time back. I *don't know it has changed in the meantime*.

See this [discussion thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03516.html) for more details.

**Update**

Take a look at John Porter's [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/index.html) module. This is not a part of standard matplotlib but a custom extension. Never used it myself so can't say much about its usefulness.

Answer (score 11):

I certainly understand your reason for needing a 3d bar plot; i suspect that's why they were created.

The libraries ('toolkits') in Matplotlib required to create 3D plots are *not* third-party libraries, etc., rather they are *included in the base Matplotlib installation*. 
(This is true for the current stable version, which is 1.0, though i don't believe it was for 0.98, so the change--from 'add-on' to part of the base install--occurred within the past year, i believe)

So here you are:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as PLT
import numpy as NP

fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xpos = NP.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
ypos = NP.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
num_elements = 10
zpos = NP.zeros(num_elements)
dx = NP.ones(10)
dy = NP.ones(10)
dz = NP.random.randint(1, 5, 10)

ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='#8E4585')
PLT.show()
```

To create 3d bars in Maplotlib, you just need to do three (additional) things:

1. import ***Axes3D*** from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
2. call the ***bar3d*** method (in my scriptlet, it's called by *ax1* an instance of the Axes class). The method signature:

   bar3d(x, y, z, dy, dz, color='b', zsort="average", *args, **kwargs)
3. pass in an additional argument to add_subplot, ***projection='3d'***

[image]

Comment: wow thxs a lot!.. i'll try to install the mpl_toolkits.mplot3d and then i'll try to see if its possible to do what i want

Comment: this toolkit is part of the base matplotlib install now (i believe this started with 1.0, which is the current stable release), so either you already have it, or just upgrade Matplotlib to get it.