# Transparent 3D bar graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to generate 3D bar graphs with transparent surfaces so that I can see what is going on behind tall bars.

The [mplot3d API docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html) say that keywords are allowed for the `bar3d` function. I pass all the required parameters but can only output graphs with solid surfaces. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501771/how-to-make-a-3d-effect-on-bars-in-matplotlib) and [these](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) bar graphs clearly show semi-transparent surfaces.

I tried the keyword `alpha` (as it is used elsewhere for a similar purpose) but that was not recognized:

```
Exception Value:  bar3d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alpha'
```

and the `zsort` parameter doesn't seem to be working either although it is used in one of the examples above:

```
Exception Value: bar3d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zsort'
```

How can I generate transparent bar graphs?